# Is there a NULL SKAction method for SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have multiple SKSpriteNodes that I keep in an array, I also keep their SKActions in an array.  This code is just an example I trimmed down, there are many more.

I wrote it this way so that when they have to be repositioned, resized, etc. I go through the array of grouped SKActions.

```
moves.append(SKAction.follow(iconPath[0], asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1))
moves.append(SKAction.follow(iconPath[1], asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1))
moves.append(SKAction.follow(iconPath[2], asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1))
...
sizing.append(SKAction.resize(byWidth: -iSize.width/2, height: -iSize.width/2, duration: 1))
sizing.append(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0))
sizing.append(SKAction.resize(byWidth: +iSize.width/2, height: +iSize.width/2, duration: 1))
...
groups.append(SKAction.group([moves[0], sizing[0], blurs[0]]))
groups.append(SKAction.group([moves[1], sizing[1], blurs[1]]))
groups.append(SKAction.group([moves[2], sizing[2], blurs[2]]))
```

However, depending on a nodes position, it doesn't get every SKAction, as seen in the sizing array. So am using SKAction.wait set to zero. Is this kludgy? Is there another/proper way to do this?

Comment: A zero delay seems the simplest and most natural null action.  Nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: @bg2b Thank you. Just thought it would be better to double check.